# transferring information from MySQL to SQL Server every night

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008

One of our clients has a software which was customized for their needs.  We dont have access to the source code of the software, but we have access to the backend of the software which uses MySQL database. Therefore, we can access all the tables in the MySQL database. We have another software which uses MS SQL Server 2008 (database). We need to bring in the information from the tables in MySQL to MS SQL Server at the end of every day, so that we could maintain consistence between the two database (software).

I found lots of articles that go through how to send information from SQL Server to MySQL (Using Linked Servers). But not the other way around. I am new to this database stuff, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done as a "pull", running on the SQL Server side, from the MySQL database.

You'd setup the linked server, just like in the articles you found.

The "trick" (in my experience with SQL Server 2005) is to use `OPENQUERY`, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LINKEDMYSQL, 'select foo from database.table_name')
```

There were a couple of `sp_serveroptions` that I had to set (in SQL Server 2005), `rpc_out` or something along those lines.

There were a couple of different ways of referencing the OPENQUERY (as an in memory table, or a temporary table). There were some differences in resources required and in performance (for large sets). I ended up using (a relatively efficient) INSERT into a SQL Server temporary table from an OPENQUERY select against the MySQL database. Then, I processed the row in the temporary table.